# Python: How do I combine functions to one

Tags: python

I am new to python.
Need help in writing the below code as one block of code, rather than using to if statements based on values.

```
    for lines in f:                                                     

        if 'et' in lines:
            # print lines
            value = re.search('(et-\d\\/\d\\/\d)', lines)
            if value:
                interfaces = value.group(1)
                # print interfaces
                smic_dict.setdefault(pfe, []).append(interfaces)        
                pfe_interfaces.append(interfaces)

        if 'xe' in lines:
            value_xe = re.search('(xe-\d\\/\d\\/\d)', lines)
            if value_xe:
                interfaces_xe = value_xe.group(1)
                smic_dict.setdefault(pfe, []).append(interfaces_xe) 
                pfe_interfaces.append(interfaces_xe)
```

So far tried this:

```
        for lines in temp:
        if 'et' or 'xe' in lines:
            value = re.search('(et-\d\\/\d\\/\d)', lines)
            value_xe = re.search('(xe-\d\\/\d\\/\d)', lines)
            if value or value_xe:
                interfaces = value.group(1)
                pic_interfaces.append(interfaces)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also be more condense if you "merge" your two regex into one:

```
for lines in f:
    value = re.search('((?:et|xe)-\d\\/\d\\/\d)', lines)
    if value:
        interfaces = value.group(1)
        # print interfaces
        smic_dict.setdefault(pfe, []).append(interfaces)
        pfe_interfaces.append(interfaces)
```

The question mark creates a so called non-capturing group and the pipe combines both alternatives.

Comment: Thank You so Much

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't really need two `if` statements here. If the line doesn't contain `et` or `xe`, it isn't going to match either of the regexps, so you can simplify that.

Second, your `if value or value_xe:` makes sense—but then you're only using `value` in the code below, which doesn't. You need to use whichever one matched. The simplest way around this is to just use the result of `or`. In Python, `x or y` means `x` if it's truthy (which, in this case, means that there was a match, rather than `None`), `y` otherwise. So, if the first search matches, you'll get the resulting match; if not, if the second search matches, you'll get the resulting match; if not, you'll get `None`.

While we're at it, as a minor nit, calling a variable that holds a single line from a file `lines` instead of `line` is a bit confusing.

So:

```
for line in temp:
    value_et = re.search('(et-\d\\/\d\\/\d)', line)
    value_xe = re.search('(xe-\d\\/\d\\/\d)', line)
    value = value_et or value_xe
    if value:
        interfaces = value.group(1)
        pic_interfaces.append(interfaces)
```

---

A few things you could do to improve it further:

- Using `\d` to mean a literal backslash character and `d` character works, but only because `\d` happens to not be an escape sequence in Python (at least as of 3.7). You really shouldn't rely on that; better to do `\\d`.
- Use raw string literals so you don't have to escape the backslashes anywhere in the first place.
- Your capture group is your entire expression, so you don't really need a capture group at all; just take the parentheses off the patterns, and use the whole `group()` rather than `group(1)`.
- Since you want to treat the two results exactly the same, you might want to merge the two regular expressions into one, by using an alternation: match `et` or `xe`, which is spelled with a `|`.

  - If you're not doing the previous change, you'd want to make this a non-capturing group, like `(?:et|xe)`. But if you're just using the full match, you don't need that.

So:

```
for line in temp:
    value = re.search(r'(et|xe)-\d\/\d\/\d', line)
    if value:
        interfaces = value.group()
        pic_interfaces.append(interfaces)
```

Comment: @NChauhan No it doesn't. "Your capture group is your entire expression, so you don't really need a capture group at all; just take the parentheses off the patterns, and use the whole `group()` rather than `group(1)`."